# perl Spreadsheet::WriteExcel how to write formula on merged cells

Tags: excel, perl

Experts,
How can I write formula on merged field? The documentation talks about writing on a single cell. I have also gone through the store formula and repeat formula. However, I am not able to figure out what I need. My formula is simple ; just adding a bunch of columns.

I have cells D31:D33 merged and I want to write formula "=SUM(D15:D30)" in it. How can I do it?. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
  $worksheet->merge_cells('D31:D33');
  $worksheet->write_formula('D31', '=SUM(D15:D30)', $hformat3);
The code above just puts the sum on cell D31 only. I want this to spread on the whole merged field.

The second question that I have is, how can I remove unused rows?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`perldoc Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` says `$worksheet->write('A4', '=SIN(PI()/4)');`

This example (copied almost verbatim from the documentation) works for me:

```
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('perl.xls');
$worksheet   = $workbook->add_worksheet();
$worksheet->write('A1', '1');
$worksheet->write('A2', '1');
$worksheet->write('A3', '=SUM(A1:A2)');
```

A quick web search doesn't turn up anything on using `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` for removing rows. You'll probably find some other Perl modules  to do that, like `Win32::OLE` mentiond in http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=952167

Comment: Hi Robert thanks for your answer. I want to write on a merged cells. How can I do that. Sorry if I didn't make my question clear.